# Call Laravel controller action from artisan script

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am writing a command-line artisan script, and would like to take advantage of existing action which do some complex calculations.

Is it possible to call a controller action from an Artisan script?

Comment: sure, but it would be better to refactor that code out of the controller most likely

Comment: I think you need extract logic code from your controller and create a service for simplify between your controller and your script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\MyController@myMethodName');
```

To pass parameters:

```
 $params = ['param1'=>1, 'param2' => '2'];
 $controller = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\MyController');
 app()->call([$controller, 'myMethodName'], $params);
```

Comment: How do I pass parameters? This is a `POST` action, which expects a `Request` param and some other params.

Comment: @guyaloni I've updated my post with how to pass parameters. If you've typehinted with request then all you have to do is to put the params inside an request object.